# 6 GB of RAM in use, open processes only use 2

Tags: memory, emulator

I have literally no idea why this is happening. I have lately installed some Android emulators, which I thought would be the cause, but I am not able to completely identify it. Closing them seems to fix the issue, but it's weird it happens both with BlueStacks AND Nox, and RAM usage in task manager only shows a fair amount.

[image: Note how 6.4 GB are in use.]

After closing Nox, only 3.8 GB were in use, but the process in the task manager never went above 600 MB of use.

Some specs (I don't know how to post them properly):

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Home
Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz, 1800 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s)
BIOS Version/Date   American Megatrends Inc. UX430UAR.300, 10/6/2017
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 8.00 GB
Total Physical Memory   7.86 GB
Available Physical Memory   4.04 GB
Total Virtual Memory    14.6 GB
Available Virtual Memory    9.80 GB
Page File Space 6.75 GB
Page File   C:\pagefile.sys
```

I'm not sure, because I'm no expert at all in this, but if Available Physical Memory looks too low, it might be because some time ago I may have allocated some memory to the Intel Graphics thing to play a couple videogames (I think I did 3.5GB or 3GB).

Indeed, adapter settings show that:

```
Total available graphics memory: 5048 MB
Dedicated video memory: 1024 MB
System video memory: 0 MB
Shared system memory: 4024 MB
```

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: @music2myear Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.17134 Build 17134

Comment: You might have allocated memory to your GPU?  Can you confirm the amount of memory you allocated then edit your question?  However, you have 4 GB of physical memory free, which is almost, 50% of your system memory.

Comment: @Ramhound I put the info in the post now

Comment: So out of 8 GB, you have indicated you want to dedicate 1 GB to your GPU and share up to an additional 4 GB.  I am still not clear on what your actual question is.  Based on the information you provide your system performance is as expected.  While you might not have any additional user processes, Windows does, 4 GB usage does not seem unreasonable.  *Your system isn't short on virtual memory either.*

Comment: Please post a screen shot of Task Manager's "Performance" tab, "memory" page.